# Read currently selected font from a running dot matrix printer

Tags: winapi, dot-matrix, escp2

There's this program called [OKI DIPUS UTILITY](https://www.oki.com/me/printing/support/drivers-and-utilities/?id=46400101FZ01&tab=drivers-and-utilities&productCategory=dotmatrix&sku=45974803&os=ab2&lang=ac2) which is supposed to read some information from an attached printer and facilitate switching the print quality, font, character pitch, etc. However, I haven't been able to make it work and I'm wondering if there's any way of automatically (as in without looking at the physical menu) figuring out what kind of font is currently selected by the printer in my own programs. How do I run [`ReadPrinter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/readprinter) on my ML5590eco and get anything useful out of it?

Comment: Is it possible that the printer connection is unidirectional?

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, certainly, though the existence of this utility and the fact that it's linked right under the printer's product page suggests that the people at OKI probably knew how to read from it

Comment: Yeah and Samsung lets me download their scanner utility for mine, which they broke since Windows 8 or something like that. You say the tool doesn't work, right? Which printer is it and how is it hooked up?

Comment: OKI ML5590eco connected through USB

Comment: This specific printing devices will require you to test, and results may vary from device to device. Just using [OpenPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/openprinter) before ReadPrinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually impossible. The printer, at least when run under the official driver, does not support bidirectional communication.